# ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I developed a project with .NET Core 3.1.3. On localhost it works smoothly. But I got an error on the server. I did a lot of research on the internet. I tried everything that was said, but the problem did not improve.
[image]

My server features:

[image]

I changed the App Pools on the server as follows:

[image]
[image]

I uploaded the necessary files for hosting to the server:
[image]

NuGet files installed in my project below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My web config file after publishing is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Finally, my startup file is as follows

```
using DataAccess.EntityFreamwork;
using Entities.Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Business.Helper;
using Business.ManagersApp;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;



namespace Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        readonly UserManagerApp _userManagerApp = new UserManagerApp();
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddRouting();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                //.AddFacebook(options =>
                //{
                //    options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                //    options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                //})
                //.AddGoogle(options =>
                //{
                //    options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                //    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                //}).AddTwitter(options =>
                //{
                //    options.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerAPIKey"];
                //    options.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
                //}).AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
                //{
                //    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                //    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
                //})
                .AddCookie(config =>
                {
                    config.Cookie.Name = "login";
                    config.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    config.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                });
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know what else I can do

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>41e7fd2c-e5a3-4474-8f68-166bda4a7546</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and my Web.exe

My Web.Exe error

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\inetpub\Web\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root,
 ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath
(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)
   at DataAccess.EntityFreamwork.ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOpt
ionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\Users\borah\Source\Repos\Hospital\DataAccess\E
ntityFreamwork\DatabaseContext.cs:line 113
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
   at DataAccess.EntityFreamwork.Repository`1..ctor() in C:\Users\borah\Source\R
epos\Hospital\DataAccess\EntityFreamwork\Repository.cs:line 18
   at Business.Abstract.ManagerBase`1..ctor() in C:\Users\borah\Source\Repos\Hos
pital\Business\Abstract\ManagerBase.cs:line 13
   at Business.ManagersApp.UsersDetailManagerApp..ctor()
   at Business.ManagersApp.UserManagerApp..ctor() in C:\Users\borah\Source\Repos
\Hospital\Business\ManagersApp\UserManagerApp.cs:line 53
   at Web.Startup..ctor(IConfiguration configuration) in C:\Users\borah\Source\R
epos\Hospital\Web\Startup.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMat
cher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance
(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startup
Type, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<
UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\borah\Source\Repos\Hospital\We
b\Program.cs:line 10
```

Comment: Have you tried The IIS Application Pool – Advanced Settings “Enable 32-Bit Applications” – setting to False  as mentioned here https://www.davidyardy.com/blog/ancm-in-process-start-failure---shenanigans/

Comment: First check event viewer for any errors and next confirm that you have the net core hosting sdk installed.

Comment: Run some basic diagnostics to rule out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: I checked them all but it still fails :(

Comment: Add my web.exe error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows. But this time there is another problem.Ajax Post does not work.Username and Password works if it is wrong, but if the returned data is correct, it doesn't work.Now I'm dealing with this :)

[image]